# Check if a string in one file exists in another in unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that contains the version name and version number. The contents of the first file looks as-

```
File1-

<Line contains the name of product1>
package_name0_9_8 >= 1.2.3x-4.5.6
package_name0_9_8-32bit >= 3.6.1g-3.5.1
package_name0_9_8-xx >= 6.3.2v-3.0.4
<Line contains the name of product2>
anotherpackage_name0_9_8 >= 3.5.6u-3.6.5
```

And,

```
File2.xml-

<package name="package_name0_9_8" version="1.2.3x-4.4.4"/>
<package name="package_name0_9_8-32bit" version="3.6.1g-3.4.0"/>
.
.
```

Is there a way to check the existance of package_name that is present in File1 with the package_name of File2 and check if the corresponding version of package_name in File1 with that of corresponding version of package_name of File2?

I am frank that I am pretty much weak in concatenating the 'grep' and 'awk' commands along with options to be used here. Please help out.

Comment: Are you interested in a Python solution, by chance?

Comment: @user2962794: Yeah, most welcome. A Python solution would be fine.

Comment: @shellter: Thanks. Yeah, that line didn't make sense. I thought, I would output that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for a in $(sed -n '/>=/p' File1.txt | grep -o '^[^ ]*'); do for b in $(sed -n "/^$a /{s/.*>=\(.*\)$/\1/p}" File1.txt); do ((! $(grep -c "$a.*$b" File2.txt))) && (echo "$a $b" >> missing_pkgs.txt); done; done;`

this is a quick one liner - you could print it out a bit  prettier

the way this works is nested for loop that grabs both pieces separate into variables (you could do that with read and put them in on one loop if you want) and then just counts the occurences in the second file with grep and whenever there is a count of zero it will reverse the value making the test (()) turn true and echo the missing packages to the file missing_pkgs.txt

here is another quick one liner that does the same thing except more efficient with one loop and variables loaded via read

`while read each; do read a b < <(echo $each) && ((! $(grep -c "$a.*$b" File2.txt))) && (echo "$a $b" >> missing_pkgs.txt); done < <(awk '/>=/{ print $1" "$3 }' File1.txt)`

more simplified:

`while read a b; do ((! $(grep -c "$a.*$b" File2.txt))) && (echo "$a $b" >> missing_pkgs.txt); done < <(awk '/>=/{ print $1" "$3 }' File1.txt)`

Comment: Thanks! Using your idea, I tried with `sed -n "/>=/p" File1 | grep -o "^[^ ]*" > package_names` and `sed -n "/^/{s/.*>= \(.*\)/\\1/p}" File1 > package_versions`. I have just put these lines into a shell script(just to make it simpler and transaprent) and run the script. Now, the same shell script should check for `line1` of `package_names` in `File2` and then `line1` of `package_versions` with `File2`. Please help. I have much less idea in shell scripting too.

Comment: I would go with the second version since its simpler if want you could further reduce it to: while read a b; do ((! $(grep -c "$a.*$b" File2.txt))) && (echo "$a $b" >> missing_pkgs.txt); done < <(awk '/>=/{ print $1" "$3 }' File1.txt)

Comment: Got that now. And, how can I store `$1` and `$3` into two separate variables used in last part `<(awk '/>=/{ print $1" "$3 }' File1.txt)` so that they can be used in better output formatting in later part?

Comment: The while read a b; does that - if you look at the end of the script after done the output of the process substitution <(awk command) is redirected < <(awk command) at the while loop so those two fields will be read into the variables a and b for each line of output from the process substitution <(awk command).

Comment: If you want to change the current output formatting you can modify the part: echo "$a $b" >> to instead be whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's².*²s#<package name="\\(&"/>#\\1 Present#p²;s/ *>= */\\)" *version="/p' File1 > /tmp/File1.sed
sed -n -f /tmp/File1.sed File2
rm /tmp/File1.sed
```

- not in on instruction like awk could do, but do the job (posix version so `--posix` on GNU sed
- you could change the output message that is the `\\1 Present` text where `\\1` will the be the package name (with few modification, version could also be used)

Comment: Or you could send output of first command into second: `sed -n 'stuff' File1 | sed -n -f - File2`

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: May I know what the square symbol does in the first line? I'm not familiar with that symbol. Also, can you please elaborate on the second bullet-point?

Comment: the `#` like the `²` are used here as pattern separator for the traditionnal `s///` instead of `/` that is used in pattern itself. sed take the fist char after `s` as separator. because it is used in 2 differnet sed (the first create the second) I use 2 different separator.

Comment: @aragaer right in bash (linux) but i use AIX KSH here so `| ... -` failed in this case unhoppefully. Good point anyway

Comment: Sorry, again! I am still not pretty much clear with that. Can that symbol be replaced? Also, please comment about `\\1 Present`

Comment: yes with any other char that does not have a particular meaning in a `s///` sed action. I use here the `²` in main sed, the one which generate the temporary sed file and `#` IN this second sed (the one generated)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already got a much shorter solution in a format closer to what you desired. However, since I asked if a Python solution would work, and you said yes, check out the code here:

http://pastebin.com/F5LYrmea

(I haven't debugged it more than a little, but it seems to work on at least a little more than your example files. I released the code to the public domain. CC-BY-SA isn't a software license, according to the makers of CC; so, that's why I didn't post it here, as posting it here would give it that license. Plus, you get syntax highlighting specific to Python at the link provided.)

Basically, it's a lot of complicated text parsing. Not much of an algorithm to explain. It gets the contents of both files, strips out the packages, their versions and the operands (puts all those in a dictionary for use later), and loops through lines of the other file and compares versions; then it tells you which ones match and which ones don't.